# Why doesn't (\w+\s?)+ match any string of words seperated by whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why this regex (\w+\s?)+ cannot group both words in a string such as "hello world", but instead only returns the last word:

```
re.findall(r"(\w+\s?)+", "hello world")
```

returns

```
['world']
```

Why does it discard "hello " in this case?

Comment: Because you are repeating the group giving you the last group only.

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?:\w+\s?)+", "hello world")`

Comment: `r"(?:\w+\s?)+"` or better `r"\w+(?:\s+\w+)*"` will match what you need.

Comment: Why not `(\w.*)` to get the whole sentence, or `(\w+)` to get each word?